# Why is using tolist() not a good approach here?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**This is not a good approach here...! can anyone say why?**

```
var dbc= new SchoolContext();
var a=dbc.Menus.ToList().Select(x=> new {
                             x.Type.Name,
                             ListOfChildmenus = x.ChildMenu.Select(cm=>cm.Name),
                             ListOfSettings = x.Settings.SelectMany(set=>set.Role)
                                         });
```

Comment: Because `ToList` creates a new `List<Menu>`(or whatever the name of the class is). This list is loaded completely into memory. Then you use `Enumerable.Select` to select an anonymous type, you could do that without creating a list first. Remove the `ToList` at the beginning and add it to the end. You should also assign it to a variable otherwise it's pointless.

Comment: Where did you get that this is not a good approach from? Its perfectly valid, not Optimised but valid.

Comment: Well, frankly, `.toList()` as it wouldn't compile. It would be useful to post code that compiles with the least fuss for those of us wishing to help. I rarely provide answers unless I can run and test my code first. Questions should be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you call `.ToList()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` and so on (when you enumerate), your query will get executed.

So when you do `dbc.Menus.ToList()` you bring in memory from the database all your Menus, and you didn't want that.

You want to bring in memory only what you select ( the list of child menus and the list of settings ).

Relevant furter reading : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading - probably you are using lazy loading

And if you want to add a filter to your IQueryable you may read about difference between ienumerable, iqueryable http://blog.micic.ch/net/iqueryable-vs-ienumerable-vs-ihaveheadache

And some dinamic filtering https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-dynamic-filtering-and-sorting-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

Actually Razvan's answer isn't totally accurate. What happens in your query is this:

1. When you call `ToList()` the contents of the entire table get dumped into memory.
2. When you access navigation properties such as `ChildMenu` and `Settings` **a new query is generated and run for each element in that table**.

If you'd done it like so:

```
dbc.Menus
.Select(x=> new {
    x.Type.Name,
    ListOfChildmenus = x.ChildMenu.Select(m=>m.Name),
    ListOfSettings = x.Settings.SelectMany(z=>z.Role)
})
.ToList()
```

your whole structure would have been generated in one query and one round trip to the database.

Also, as Alex said in his comment, it's not necessarily a bad approach. For instance if your database is under a lot of load it's sometimes better to just dump things in the web application's memory and work with them there.